# Sharepoint Custom Form with Attachments

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I want to implement a custom form that collects data from my user and not sure how the implementation will go. The company uses SharePoint as a base and would like to integrate it with that. But can't seem to find documentation regarding adding attachments can't find a proper test platform for SharePoint testing beforehand. It is an HTML form requiring people to upload their credentials. Should I use the SharePoint List? Or just do a separate SharePoint provider-hosted app?

I have tried creating an ASP.net web page then integrating to SharePoint but the integration requires an actual SharePoint account that is already running.
But I require a reasonable test environment

Users will be able to fill in their personal information and also upload some of their certificates etc.

Comment: You might want to look into PowerApps https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: but I can see that I can not share my site with users who are not in the organization. The form is to go to people who are not based in the organization i.e the customers. Does one have to have a Microsoft account to access the form once it is created? So far PowerApps creates forms but requests sign in to a microsoft account. and can not guarantee all my clients have one.

Comment: Is this not just a list? Inputting data and enable attachments?

Answer (score 1):

If You need to give the ability for some external users to put some data into Your SharePoint site without any authentication then

the correct answer depends on the SharePoint type You are using.

If we are taking about on-Prem > then the easiest would be to configure a Site to have anonymous access and create a list with all the needed fields. The users would populate the list and work on the add/edit list item form. Also here You could just add a custom webpart to some page that presents the form You want and saves the data to the list with some elevated permissions if needed.

For Online the anonymous access is not an option and here I would try with a SharePoint provider-hosted add-in that is authorized to Your SharePoint tenat via low-trust with Add-in-only policy (so the data is saved to SP on Add-ins permissions). You can read more about this here:

[Get started creating provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins)

[Creating SharePoint Add-ins that use low-trust authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/creating-sharepoint-add-ins-that-use-low-trust-authorization)

basically it is a separate web application (webForm, MVC or other) which You manage (is stored on some IIS server You or Your company should manage, or stored on Azure). You can do what ever logic or form You wish in this web app. After that You add it as a SharePoint provider hosted app with Add-in-only policy (the user that installs the add-in must have proper permission to do that). After that You can save the data from Your custom web app to SharePoint using CSOM approach with the context of the SP add-in.